# JSON data binding to a model object in controller

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding

I am using JQGRID as follows:

```
@(Html.Grid("Basic")
    .SetCaption("")
     .SetUrl("/cntrler/GetListGridData?{\"mdlobj\":" + Json.Encode(Model))
    .SetDataType(MvcJqGrid.Enums.DataType.Json)
    .SetRequestType(MvcJqGrid.Enums.RequestType.Post)
    .SetPager("pager")
    .SetHeight(400)
)
```

The "Model" above is the model object in the view page. when run, the URL will be rendered as:

```
url:'/cntrler/GetListGridData?{"mdlobj":{"PLANT":"1","DEPT":"5","CRIB":"5"}'
```

"PLANT","DEPT","CRIB" are properties in the Model object.

And I have my controller method which gets called:

```
[HttpPost]
public string GetListGridData(ReceiptIndexViewModel mdlobj, GridSettings gridSettings)
    {
        var mdl = mdlobj;
    }
```

The issue is that, I am not seeing mdlobj properties values as posted from view page. Those are all nulls.

Can some one tell me how do I bind the values posted from view page through JSON to a model object in controller?

Comment: You can try something like `.SetUrl(Url.Action("GetListGridData", "cntrler",Model))`

Comment: Thanks..That worked. But, I wonder, how do I work it with JSON?